# Exporting a plot in GUI-less pyqtgraph

Tags: qt, export, pyqtgraph

I'm using the fabulous `pyqtgraph` in a script which creates a plot and exports it to a file (no interactive features are used). It works great.

However, when running it on a remote machine, with no X server, an error is raised in `mkQApp()`:

`cannot connect to X server`

***Is there a way to run pyqtgraph GUI-less-ly*, removing the dependency on X?**

I found there's a `QtCore.QCoreApplication` class, which, as to my understanding, is GUI-less.  However, I'm not familiar enough with Qt to tell whether it can (or does) work with pyqtgraph.

Comment: I _think_ the answer is no -- there is no way to have QGraphicsView render to an image without a QApplication created. However I am not entering an answer because I hope someone else will tell us otherwise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use `QGraphicsScene` without a `QApplication`:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
>>> app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([])
>>> scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
Segmentation fault
```

**However**, you should be able to use [xvfb](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) in the absence of any graphics hardware, and thus use your usual pyqtgraph script unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, using xvfb works great. I understand the limitation is originating in the Qt level, but is it possible to support some GUI-less mode in pyqtgraph, which avoids using the Qt classes which don't work GUI-less-ly? Or is pyqtgraph already heavily depending on them for its core functionality?

Comment: For now, pyqtgraph depends very heavily on Qt GraphicsView to generate all graphics. A long term goal, however, is to transition to using OpenGL (via the VisPy project) instead. This will provide many new features, including headless rendering.